# Mailchimp interegation with HTML template, doesnt work. Bootstrap HTML, CSS, Jquery, Javascript

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, mailchimp

I have this page: http://www.indiespil.dk/aitasi-under-construction-page/Aitasi/image/

The subscribe button, I need it to work with Mailchimp - is this even possible? It's a HTML template i have downloaded from Mojo-themes.

Please ask, and I will find the appropriate codes for you, but I honestly have no idea where to find it.

The index file looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Aitasi - Under Construction Page</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

    <section id="home-page">
        <div class="container-fluid home-bg">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center home-page">
                    <div class="main-logo">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <!-- COUNTDOWN -->      
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 tk-countdown">
                                <div class="row">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /COUNTDOWN -->
                    </div>
                    <p>Subscribe to our newsletter</p>
                    <div class="form-group subscribe-area">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control subscribe-box" placeholder="Enter your email">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg submit-bt" >Subscribe</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 social-shear text-center">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/indiespil"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://www.twitter.com/indiespil"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://plus.google.com/+IndiespilDk1/posts"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                    </div><!-- /.social-shear -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section><!-- /#home-page -->


                </div>
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </section><!-- /#about-page -->

    <section id="about-page">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <h1 class="about-title">A Danish indie game store</h1>
                    <h2>For Danish Indie Gamers</h2>
                    <p>Cool features include</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center service">
                    <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i>
                    <h3 class="whiteTextOverride">Competitions</h3>
                    <p>Every week we'll have a featured game on sale. Be the fastest on the chosen level and win great prices.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center service">
                    <i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i>
                    <h3 class="whiteTextOverride">Game wallet</h3>
                    <p>One place for all your games. Simple.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center service">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                    <h3 class="whiteTextOverride">Indie Coins</h3>
                    <p>Buy a game and get rewarded with Indie Coins. Spend your coins on new games. You can also find our easter eggs and get rewarded...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center service">
                    <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                    <h3 class="whiteTextOverride">Community</h3>
                    <p>We'll gather all Danish indie gamers in our cozy environment.</p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </section><!-- /#service-page -->


                </div>
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </section><!-- /#about-page -->

    <section id="service-page">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <h1 class="service-title">Features</h1>
                    <h2>For developers</h2>
                    <p>Our goal is to remove every obtacle for you, making it easy to be a part of IndieSpil.dk</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center service">
                    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                    <h3>Easy updates</h3>
                    <p>No need for you to spend time on updating your game - Send us a link, and we'll do the rest.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center service">
                    <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i>
                    <h3>Reviews</h3>
                    <p>We make a video game review in Danish of every game on our store.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center service">
                    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                    <h3>Sales stats</h3>
                    <p>Don't worry about finding and analyzing sales stats - We will report to you directly on the 1st of each month.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center service">
                    <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
                    <h3>Marketing</h3>
                    <p>We will take care of marketing your game in Denmark - we will reach above 100.000 Danish gamers in an instant.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center service">
                    <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
                    <h3>Our budget</h3>
                    <p>Over 90% of our profit goes back to marketing your game</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center service">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                    <h3>Contract</h3>
                    <p>Our contract is written for people, easy to understand, short and without anything hidden. Yet it's still written by a great lawyer.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center service">
                    <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
                    <h3>Quality Assurance</h3>
                    <p>We only accept great games on our website - IndieSpil.dk will not be watered down by bad games. Make sure you fit in!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center service">
                    <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                    <h3>Our Community</h3>
                    <p>We will take care of our community's response to your game, you wont have to spend time reading comments and replying.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center service">
                    <i class="fa fa-flag"></i>
                    <h3>Localizing</h3>
                    <p>In Denmark people prefer to play games in English. No need to change language, just because we're a Danish store.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center service">
                    <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>
                    <h3>Translation</h3>
                    <p>We will take care of translating descriptions, tags and meta.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center service">
                    <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
                    <h3>SEO & Adwords</h3>
                    <p>We have a SEO expert making SEO for our website, resulting in rank 1 on google. We spend a large amount of our profits on Adwords.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center service">
                    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
                    <h3>Exposure</h3>
                    <p>Talk to us, and we might feature your game on the front page.</p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </section><!-- /#service-page -->


    <section id="about-page">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <h1 class="about-title">About Us</h1>
                    <h2>The team</h2>
                    <p>We're a team of three Danish young entrepreneurs</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center member">
                    <div class="member-img">
                        <img src="images/01.jpg" alt="" />
                        <div class="member-social">
                            <a class="facebook-icon" href="https://www.facebook.com/michael.himmelstrup?fref=ts"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            <a class="twitter-icon" href="https://dk.linkedin.com/in/michaelhimmelstrup"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Michael Himmelstrup</h3>
                    <span>Graphics Designer</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center member">
                    <div class="member-img">
                        <img src="images/02.jpg" alt="" />
                        <div class="member-social">
                            <a class="facebook-icon" href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100002489468218"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            <a class="twitter-icon" href="https://dk.linkedin.com/pub/emil-kristensen/a5/3a3/b83"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Emil Frølund</h3>
                    <span>Founder</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center member">
                    <div class="member-img">
                        <img src="images/03.jpg" alt="" />
                        <div class="member-social">
                            <a class="facebook-icon" href="https://www.facebook.com/Magmismo?fref=ts"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            <a class="twitter-icon" href="http://dk.linkedin.com/in/christianagerup"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Christian Agerup</h3>
                    <span>Web Developer</span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </section><!-- /#about-page -->

    <section id="contact-page">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form-area text-center" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                        <h1 class="contact-title">Get in touch</h1>
                        <h2>Feel free to contact us</h2>
                        <p></p>
                        <div class="contact-form">
                            <div class="col-sm-5 your-name col-sm-offset-1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name...">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-5 your-email">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Enter your email...">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10 your-message col-sm-offset-1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your message..."></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg submit-button" >Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div><!--/.row-->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </section><!-- /#contact-page -->

    <!-- JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/countdown.js"></script><!-- Countdown -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script><!-- Scripts -->

</body>
```

Comment: Mailchimp ? For email ? You need to use inline styles and **no JS at all**

Comment: Okay, will you help me out? Is it possible for me to make that "subscribe" button you can see on the webpage now, into a mailchimp form? So that when people subscribe they join my mailchimp list?

Comment: No I can only help on the template part

Comment: Okay, so you suggest that I remove this subscribe button and make a new one+

Comment: I just mean to say ,if the above code u r going to use in your email template then it won't work .Emails cannot contain external files and JS.

Comment: you need to use inline styling for css and no js files. no bootstrap and other css file u include make an email template with inline style using style tag